# Firebase jobdispatcher should work only when screen is on

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

I created a widget, that has an internal service that update the data every 15 minutes.
For the timer, I am using fire base job service.
In order to reduce battery usage, I want to make sure that the jobs will be performed only when the screen is on.
Is there any option to do it (like in alarm manager)??

Comment: ON_ANY_NETWORK, ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK, DEVICE_CHARGING, DEVICE_IDLE these four constraint are available while scheduling firebase job service